# Changing geometry/material of mesh with distance

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I'm making a game with three.js in which an mesh will be rendered in greater detail as the player gets closer (i.e different geometry and material). This seems like it would be a common requirement in open world type games, and I was wondering what standard procedure is in three.js

It looks like changing the geometry of a mesh is quite computationally costly, so should I just store a different mesh for each distance, or is there an existing data structure for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use level-of-detail (LOD) modeling.

There is an example of that in the following three.js example: http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_lod.html

In the example, press the 'W/S' keys to see the effect.

three.js r.62

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising. Can LOD modelling be applied to different textures as well?

Comment: On closer inspection, looks like I should be able to. Cheers!